# I'm trying to sum the 5 number that entered by the user but it doesn't calculate. in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, sum, numbers, c#-3.0

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] numbers = new int[5];
    int sum = 0;
    int i;
    Console.WriteLine("Input 5 elements in the array :");
   
    for (i= 0; i < numbers.Length; i++) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"element index {i}: ");
        numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    
    sum = sum + numbers[i];
    
    Console.WriteLine("The sum of the elements of the array is " + sum);
    Console.ReadLine();
    

}
```

I need it like that

Input 5 elements in the array :

element index 0: 1

element index 1: 1

element index 2: 1

element index 3: 1

element index 4: 1

Expected Output : The sum of the elements of the array is 5

Comment: So what *does* the code do at the moment? Have you debugged through it?

Comment: (Hint: how many times are you adding anything to `sum`, and how many times *should* you be adding something to `sum`?) Note that if you'd declared `i` inside the for loop declaration, the code wouldn't even compile - the compiler would have helped you to find the problem before you even ran it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "summing" is occurring OUTSIDE the loop, the correction is as follows:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        
       int[] numbers = new int[5];
       int sum = 0;
       int i;


       Console.WriteLine("Input 5 elements in the array :");
   
       for (i= 0; i < numbers.Length; i++) 
       {

           Console.WriteLine($"element index {i}: ");

           numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

           sum = sum + numbers[i];

       }
    
       Console.WriteLine("The sum of the elements of the array is " + sum);
       Console.ReadLine();
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful! I just have another question how I can make the (i) in this line - Console.WriteLine($"element index {i}: "); -
change to a number for each index.

Comment: @red - Can you clarify what you mean by "change to a number for each index"?  The variable i is an int (a number) and the value of the variable i will be displayed, for example, when the statement Console.WriteLine($"element index {i}: ") executes the value of i will be displayed.